# How do I handle large files in qpython?

Tags: android, python-2.7, filesystems, qpython

I write a little downloader, but it don't work when the file's size exceeds `2*31-1` bytes. It reminds me that the python integer is too large to be converted to `C long`.

How do I solve this problem? I usually use it to download the video,but I do not know much about video coding, can I cut the `".mkv"` video and play it directly?

Comment: So Python integer is 32 bits. And a long from C? You should have informed us of course. And what would be the problem if you use python? Dont understand a word.

Comment: What is the actual error? A stripped down sample of code that triggers it would be helpful too